# Passing variables for installer python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a application that lets you pass in a discord webhook (string value) into a different .py file, then I want to make this .py file into a .exe file. I have no problem with making the applications gui, but I have no idea how I can pass in the webhook value, with converting it to a .exe file I also have no problem.

Does anyone know how I could pass in the webhook string permanently without using other file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

just open the file and write the variable lines to it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).